# Url / Path helpers not working after upgrade to Rails 6.1 from 6.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

After having upgraded to Ruby 3.0.6 and, subsequently, to Rails 6.1.7.3, we are having issues with all the URL helpers used in views.

They all fail with the error:

```
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1)
     # /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.6@app/gems/actionpack-6.1.7.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:170:in `url_for'
```

The only way I can rescue this is by explicitly adding `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to each helper, but this is very hard to handle because the project is big.

(for example `root_path` becomes `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_path`)

Searching around, I have not found anything helpful. Is there something anyone can help with?

Comment: Can you post a line of code that is actually causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the error was produced by the way routing was called from ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.

Not sure if this is valid, but it produced a functional outcome, so here I post it.

I created a module override to rescue the erroneous behaviour:

```
ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection::UrlHelper.module_eval do

  def call(t, method_name, args, inner_options, url_strategy)
    controller_options = t.url_options
    options = controller_options.merge @options
    hash = handle_positional_args(controller_options,
                                  inner_options || {},
                                  args,
                                  options,
                                  @segment_keys)
    begin
      t._routes.url_for(hash, route_name, url_strategy, method_name)
    rescue
      # this fixes the behaviour for views
      t._routes.url_for(hash)
    end
  end

end
```